# install zabbix 2.4 error

Tags: installation, centos6, zabbix

I install zabbix 2.4 on centos 6 but it error:

> ---> Package zabbix-web.noarch 0:3.0.3-1.el7 will be an update 
>   --> Processing Dependency: php-ldap for package: zabbix-web-3.0.3-1.el7.noarch
>   
> --> Running transaction check
>   
> ---> Package php56-ldap.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.124.amzn1 will be installed
>   
> ---> Package zabbix-server-mysql.x86_64 0:3.0.3-1.el7 will be obsoleting
>   
> --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.3-1.el7.x86_64
>   
> --> Processing Dependency: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit) for package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.3-1.el7.x86_64
>   
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>   
> Error: Package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.3-1.el7.x86_64 (zabbix)
>              Requires: libnetsnmp.so.31()(64bit)
>   
> Error: Package: zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.3-1.el7.x86_64 (zabbix)
>              Requires: systemd

Please help me, Thanks so much

Comment: This would be better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You are installing Zabbix 3.0 for Centos 7. Use the correct repo for Centos 6 from the Zabbix [download page](http://www.zabbix.com/download.php) no matter if version 2.4 or 3.0.

Centos 6 does not come with systems, thus the dependency error.

Comment: I have install Zabbix 3.0 but not succes then I remove it, after that I using: rpm -Uvh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-2.4-1.el6.noarch.rpm -> yum install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql.

Comment: Seems that you didn't successfully remove the reference to the 3.0 repo. I'm not a Centos/RHEL user and StackOverflow is for programming, not for sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install zabbix 2.4 on CentOS 6.X, run these commands:

```
yum -y http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-2.4-1.el6.noarch.rpm
yum -y install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql
```

But you better to install zabbix 3.0, because it is LTS (Long Term Support). In order to install Zabbix 3.0 on CentOS 6.X, run these commands:

```
yum -y localinstall http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.0/rhel/6/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm
yum -y install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql
```